# Uber web request widget

Tags: uber-api

I'm looking for a solution for integrating, a seamless ride request experience, into a web application (running on desktop or mobile).

I understand there is a [widget](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/ride-request-widget) that could be embedded in a mobile application. I would like to get a similar experience in a web application.

I also understand that the [Uber request API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests) supports this, and I could implement this from scratch. I'm hoping someone developed this kind of widget, so I can integrate it into my application.

Answer (score 2):

The ride request widget was built from our rest apis, but was intended for the mobile audience. You can see how it works in the sdks: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/ride-request-widget

You can build the same functionality for a web app using our rest apis and it is covered in the ride request api tutorial here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorials-rides-api